# How to prevent scrollbar from showing when launching a web app

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, scrollbar

I'm developing a web application for Firefox OS, i'm using HTML 5 and jQuery Mobile for this app,

I'm using different pages and give the user the ability to swipe between pages

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1"></div>

$.mobile.changePage('#p'+i, {
    transition: "slide"
});
```

some pages need scrolling, some don't. When I swipe from one page to another, the appearance of a scrollbar moves the page a few pixels to the side. and it's affecting the swipe as well. Is there any way to avoid this without explicitly showing the scrollbars on each page?

I tried to add scroll to all the pages but still have the same problem :

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

It works when disable scroll completely, but I want always to have the scroll ability without showing the scroll bar, or showing it after page load.

Answer (score 0):

> I want always to have the scroll ability without showing the scroll bar, or showing it after page load.

You won't be able to have scroll functionality if the scroll bar is not visible.
You will probably have to use some external scripts such as [iScroll.js](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5)  or similar.

The scroll bar is created on document ready and updated on document load. Delaying its appearance to `on load`won't make any improvement to your problem as far as I understood.